# How to place heading and paragraph tags inline

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to place a heading and paragraph tags side by side (inline) like this

[image]

Using bootstrap 4, here's how I have attempted to do it

```
<div class="col-md-1 text-left">
    <span class="d-inline">
        <h2>
            {{ event.formattedDate.slice(9, -15) }}
        </h2>
    </span>
    <span class="d-inline">
        <p>{{ event.formattedDate.slice(5, -17) }}</p>
        <p>{{ event.formattedDate.slice(0, 3) }}</p>
    </span>
</div>
```

This gives me this instead

[image]

How can I make this work?

Comment: `try - .col-md-1 {display: flex; flex-direction: row;}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inline CSS Image and Paragraph inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48093819/inline-css-image-and-paragraph-inline)

Comment: Actually using bootstrap `d-flex flex-row` did the trick

Comment: https://validator.nu/ — your HTML is invalid. Write valid HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You should not place block elements (like `<h2>` and `<p>`) inside inline elements (like `<span>`. [You can read about it here.](https://delete.atlassian.net/browse/MSB-370?focusedCommentId=207266)

You should go with a flex container, like so:

```css
.box {
  /* this is what you want */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 16px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 64px;
}

p {
  font-size: 24px;
}

h2, p {
  margin: 0;
}

.box div {
  margin-right: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <div>
        <h2>
            08
        </h2>
    </div>
    <span>
        <p>Aug</p>
        <p>Sat</p>
    </span>
</div>
```

Have fun and go build something great!

Comment: Thanks, I have removed the span around the h2 tag and used `d-flex flex-row` class on the parent div.

Comment: Great, just make sure you understand what these classes do behind the scenes. That way you won't run into trouble when you place stuff inside flex containers 

Answer (score 0):

will this works for you?

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="d-flex">
    <h1>8</h1>
    <div class="row ml-2">
    <span class="col-12">month</span>
    <span class="col-12">day</span>
    </div>
</div>
```